# How to wrap a proto message in a go model

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am currently working on moving our rest api based go service to gRPC, using protobuf. it's a huge service with a lot of APIs and already in production so i don't want to make so many changes to ruin the existing system.

So i want to use my go models as source of truth, and to generate .proto messages i think i can manage with this - [Generate proto file from golang struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724556/generate-proto-file-from-golang-struct)

Now my APIs also expect the request and response according to the defined go models, i will change them to use the .proto models for request and response. but when request/response is passed i want to wrap them in my go models and then the rest of the code doesn't need any changes.

In that case if the request is small i can simply copy all the fields in my go model but in case of big requests or nested models it's a big problem.

1) Am i doing this right way ?

2) No, what's the right way ?

3) Yes, how i can copy the big proto messages to go model and vice-versa for response ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the go models as the source of truth, why you do want to use the .proto generated ones for the REST request/response? Is it because you'd like to use [proteus service generation](https://github.com/src-d/proteus#generate-services) (and share the code between REST and gRPC)?

Usually, if you wanted to migrate from REST to gRPC, the most common way probably would be to use [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) (note that since around 1.10.x you can use it [in-process without resorting to the reverse proxy](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/pull/947)), but this would be "gRPC-first", where you derive REST from that, while it seems you want "REST- first", since you have your REST APIs already in production. In fact for this reason grpc-gateway probably wouldn't be totally suitable, because it could generate slightly different endpoints from your existing ones. It depends on how much can you afford to break backward compatibility (maybe you could generate a "v2" set of APIs and keep the old "v1" around for a little while, giving time to existing clients to migrate).